# Mutator for file upload

Tags: laravel, file

I need to write to a table path for an uploaded file. I am waiting for path same uploads/fileName1540886604.jpg, but I am getting a path same /tmp/phpQOolst.

form.blade.php

```
<input type="file" name="file">
```

PostController.php

```
public function store(Request $request, Post $post)
    {
$fileName = "fileName" . time() . '.' . $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();;
    $path = $request->file("file")->storeAs('uploads', $fileName, 'public');

 $post->setAttribute('file', $path);
 $post = $post->create($request->all())
```

Post.php

```
class Post extends Model
{

   protected $fillable = ['name', 'slug', 'content', 'file', 'published', 'created_by'];

public function setFileAttribute($value)
{
    //dd($value);
    $this->attributes['file'] = $value;
}
```

When I add code dd($value) I get uploads/fileName1540886604.jpg for a test, but it's commented, it's stored  /tmp/phpQOolst.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting $post with everything from the request.

It would be better to do something like

```
$path = $request->file("file")->storeAs('uploads', $fileName, 'public');
$post = new Post($request->all());
$post->file = $path;
$post->save();
```

Or shorter

```
$path = $request->file("file")->storeAs('uploads', $fileName, 'public');
$request->merge(['file' => $path]); //Overwrite file in the request
$post = Post::create($request->all());
```

But a disadvantage would be that you no longer have access to the File object so

```
$post = Post::create($request->except('file')->toArray() + ['file' => $path]);
```

Could also work

Answer (score 0):

you can use mutator to save file directly

```
public function setFileAttribute($file)
{
    $fileName = "fileName" . time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $path = $file->storeAs('uploads', $fileName, 'public');
    $this->attributes['file'] = $path;
}
```

then in controller you need to create post only :

```
$post = Post::create($request->all());
```

Comment: But what happens if you want to change just the url?

Comment: what do you mean with change url ? , if you mean updating file you can add in mutator function check if it has old file then delete it then add new uploaded file .